# Sql server exception: the statement did not return a result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL query that runs fine in SQL Server Management Studio, but when I copy and paste it into jasperreports's iReport to make a report, it gives me a SQL Server exception and says the statement did not return a result set. This has left me confused.

The query is:

```
declare @index int = 1

declare @t Table(ID INT, DI INT, INDBOOK1 INT, INDBOOK2 INT, delta INT)

while(@index < 18)
begin
   INSERT INTO @t
      select distinct top 18
         col1.ID,
         col1.DI,
         col1.INDBOOK as INDBOOK1,
         col2.INDBOOK as INDBOOK2,
         col2.INDBOOK - col1.INDBOOK 
      FROM  
          table as col1
      inner join 
          table as col2 on col2.ID = @index 
                        and col2.DI = col1.DI+1 
      where 
          col1.ID = @index

   set @index = @index + 1
end

select ID, DI, INDBOOK1, INDBOOK2, delta FROM @t
```

Does anybody know why this is giving me the no result set returned exception?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Probably because the tool you are using is not very good at parsing your SQL. Do you really need a loop to do this? I don't think so.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I agree with you. But how do I do this task without looping?

Comment: I'd love to guide you, but based on what currently fails I'm not sure that a CTE or a join or any complex SQL whatsoever also won't break your reporting tool.

Comment: Alright. Thanks a lot for your input.

Comment: Do you really need the distinct there? Is there a problem with the data model? I started re-writing the query as a set instead of a loop, but the distinct is throwing me off.

Comment: The distinct isn't really necessary. A few rows of the data are duplicated so I was getting rid of them, but the duplicate rows are less then 10 in number, so I could do without the distinct.

Comment: I am guessing here, but report tool is maybe failing because it does not recognize a batch of several commands, and is executing only the first one. Try rewriting your query as a stored procedure and executing it from report tool.

Comment: You are probably correct. I can sort of solve this problem by copying and pasting the code inside the while 18 times and then it works. So it seems my reporting tool doesn't like the while structure that I have set up. However this solution is inefficient for looping over large numbers. I'll try the stored procedure execution. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tough to tell without sample data etc. but I think this should be close to what you need, in a single statement with no explicit loops:

```
;WITH x([index]) AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (18) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number)
  FROM master..spt_values ORDER BY number
),
y AS 
(
  SELECT [index] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1.ID ORDER BY col1.ID),
         col1.ID, col1.DI, col1.INDBOOK as INDBOOK1, col2.INDBOOK as INDBOOK2,
         col2.INDBOOK - col1.INDBOOK as delta
      FROM dbo.table as col1
      INNER JOIN dbo.table as col2 
        ON col2.ID = col1.ID
        AND col2.DI = col1.DI+1 
)
SELECT y.ID, y.DI, y.INDBOOK1, y.INDBOOK2, y.delta
FROM x INNER JOIN y
ON x.[index] = y.[index]
WHERE y.[index] <= 18;
```